# Rules in Firebase database revert to original

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm developing a proof-of-concept application, and thus my security requirements are low. I therefore changed the access rules to public access:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

This works as expected. The problem is that after a few minutes, the rules change back to default values (auth required) and I get an access error "Error: permission_denied at /cases: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data."

Why on earth is this so?

Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing in Firebase itself that would revert your rules. Do you have auto-deploy process that could be triggering this change (e.g. running `firebase deploy` from a build process)?

Comment: That was the question, yes: I was changing the rules on the web console, but `firebase deploy`was overwriting that change. I was not even aware the database.rules.json file existed...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You must edit database.rules.json in your IDE then save it then deploy it.